# Can a virtual PC find out the identity of its host?

Tags: python, virtual-machines, virtualization

There's a Microsoft Virtual PC instance on my network that runs build scripts and reports problems by sending me an e-mail.  I don't what machine it's running on!  I can access the machine by Remote Desktop, but I don't know how to work out the host from that.  What I'd really like, in the future, is to include the host name in the automated e-mail.  So I have two questions:

1) If you're logged onto a virtual PC, is there any way of finding out the identity of the host machine?

2) If the answer to question 1 is yes, what's the easiest way to find the host automatically from a Python script?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless I am mistaken, outside of server-provided virtualization tools (like VMware's 'vmware tools'), you won't be able to determine even that the VM *is* a virtual machine.

Perhaps running through Hyper-V's admin consoles you could determine which machine it is running on. Outside of that, I know of no such way to determine what you're looking for.

Comment: You can usually tell from the outside. If you scan it, it won't look quite like a regular system. (If nothing else, if you use nmap on it, the MAC address will almost always resolve to "VMware" or something similar.

Comment: You can also usually tell via CPU features or DMI information when you are on the virtual machine.

Comment: Thought that might be the answer.  Hey ho.  Thanks.

Comment: if you back-lookup the MAC address, yes it can come back. But if it's been masked (seen that a *lot*, personally) - it won't. On Virtuozzo (what my VPS uses), the CPUs are passed-through, and the MAC address looks 'normal'.

Answer (score 2):

Hah. Came in here to tell you I'd struck out, *unless* you were (for some reason) using Microsoft VM instead of VMWare.

Microsoft puts the name of the physical host in the registry of the virtual machine under:

```
HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Virtual Machine\Guest\Parameters\PhysicalHostName
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Only if you have "Virtual PC Additions" installed in the guest.

Answer (score 1):

Worst case scenario: Locate it based on it's network connection, just as you would for a rogue machine. I start by determining which switch port it's connected to and then look up where that cable terminates.